# Bootstrap 3 Adding text from a button click and display in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and trying to populate a form in one tab with the text that is generated when clicking a link in another tab. Using standard tab setup.
When the user selects a schedule in one Tab there is a

```
<a href="#dates" data-toggle="tab">Book Now</a>
```

that correctly guides them to the Form.tab that I need them to fill out. The problem is that it is missing the string I need in the message field.

So how do I get that done?
I've tried jquery and had no luck so far. Would appreciate a helping hand on this one.

### EDIT

Solved thanks to a friend! The solution was using in first running

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

to be able to manipulate the page, and

```
$('#someComponentsText').val($(this).text()); })
```

to grab the text I needed and insert in into the component I required.
I made a simple Bootply example showing the jquery required... view here http://www.bootply.com/DPoaz49nSb

Comment: Try to make a Bootply demonstrating the issue. It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. http://www.bootply.com/

Answer (score 0):

Once the item in question is generated, populate the value of the form field (I am assuming it is a text input) like this with JQuery:

```
$('#yourid').val(valuegenerated);
```

Replace 'yourid' with the ID of the element you want to populate and replace 'valuegenerated' with the value generated. Add that code to the generation routine at the bottom.

Comment: I edited my original post with an example. The trouble I had with *valuegenerated* was that I had several links on the same page - each with its own value that I needed, whereas value generated had the same value for all links. Thanks kindly @MichealMahony.